# grep and AWK command to read host name and print columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

am using below simple grep & AWK commands to Match the hostname and print ID from the CSV file.

My command:

```
#!/bin/bash
host=`hostname`
/bin/cat /tmp/MasterInventory.csv | grep -i $host | awk -F, '{print $1}' > /opt/input_appProfile.id
```

My CSV Inventory:

```
Hostname                  App_ID       
SercverTest345             12               
Mytestserver01             17               
Mytestserver02             19
```

If the cmd searching for `Mytestserver02` it is printing App_ID `17` & `19`, but actually it should print only `19` as per hostname

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: why did you write `awk -F,` if your csv file has no comma ?

Comment: Something like `awk -v host="Mytestserver01" '$1==host{print $2}' /tmp/MasterInventory.csv` should work for your case btw, but I think there are many duplicates for your question.

Comment: Your solution would only match the _exact_ host name. His usage of grep seems to indicate he wants partial matches, too. Therefore: `awk -v host="Mytestserver01" '$1~host{print $2}' /tmp/MasterInventory.csv`

Comment: You say "My CSV" and show a file with no commas. Is what you posted REALLY your input file format (i.e. it's not a CSV) or are you trying to show us a representation of a CSV file that you think is easier to read? [edit] your question to either show us a CSV file or get rid of the test that says it's a CSV file (and state what it really is, e.g. mulit-space or tab separated or fixed width fields)

Answer (score 1):

*Edited after comments:*

Here is a pure `awk` solution:

```
awk -v host="$(hostname)" 'tolower($1)~tolower(host){print $2}' /tmp/MasterInventory.csv > /opt/input_appProfile.id
```

Here is a solution using `grep`in case that is what you prefer:

```
grep -i `hostname` /tmp/MasterInventory.csv | awk '{print $1}' > /opt/input_appProfile.id
```

Advantage of the pure `awk` over the solution with `grep` is you only match the first column instead of the whole line. Plus if you use `==` instead of `~`, you can make sure that you're only getting exact host name matches.

Comment: You don't need to export the variable as you are using the grep inside the same bash script

Comment: You never need grep when you're using awk since awk can do anything useful that grep can do.

Comment: @EdMorton Since we're doing case insensitive search and `IGNORECASE` is a gawkism, the only solution I can come up with is `awk -v host="Mytestserver01" 'tolower($1)~tolower(host){print $2}' /tmp/MasterInventory.csv`... And that is, in my opinion, less pretty and readable than `grep -i`.

Comment: Yes, that would be the non-gawk way to do case-insensitive test but more importantly note that your awk script without grep is suddenly more robust as you're now only checking for hostname in the first field, not across the whole line as you are with grep, and if you make it `==` instead of `~` then it becomes more robust still as you'd now be doing a string comparison instead of regexp AND you'd no longer have false successes on partial matches. You're going from a hope-and-prayer grep solution to a rock solid awk solution. I didn't downvote you btw!

Comment: Thanks, good points. Although we don't know if the partial matches (`~`instead of `==`) were intended by the original solution. About the downvotes: Obviously I deserve them :-P

Comment: We also don't know if the OP deliberately left `host` unquoted so the shell could performing globbing and he can deliberately introduce security vulnerabilities but we can guess... ;-).